# AttributeError: object has no attribute '_type_equality_funcs'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting following error with Unittest module implement for my program

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 493, in _getAssertEqualityFunc
    asserter = self._type_equality_funcs.get(type(first))
AttributeError: 'Utility' object has no attribute '_type_equality_funcs'
```

when i am trying to create a common class and try to execute  through common class utility test functions getting above errors  but with normal Unittest class implementation  no error was getting.

below is detail explanation of program which executing without any errors

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest', param=None):
        super(BaseTestCase, self).__init__(methodName)
        self.param = param

    @staticmethod
    def parametrize(testcase_klass, param=None):

        testloader = unittest.TestLoader()
        testnames = testloader.getTestCaseNames(testcase_klass)
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        for name in testnames:
            suite.addTest(testcase_klass(name, param=param))
        return suite
```

Now i am inheriting BaseTestCase class and calling testcases..

```
     class salesgrowth_DevInt(BaseTestCase):
          def setUp(self):
                print "constructor"
                pwd = os.getcwd()

     def test4_refactoring(self,log):
             if (STATUS.lower() == "completed" or STATUS == "Actor : SUCCESS"):`enter code here`
                  self.assertEqual(os.stat(OUTPUT + '/tes1.txt').st_size, 0,
                 'employee count  is not matching with master data . Different  entries are in test1.txt\n')
```

upto this everything working ok

now like salesgrowth_DevInt testcases there is no of other testcases which inheriting BaseTestCase and executing test4_refactoring testcases(here for example testcases no of lines removed) , to avoid duplication of code
i have created common class Utility includes test4_refactoring function serving to all the  testcases like salesgrowth_DevInt .

below is  Common utility class code

```
import sys
import json, sys, os, argparse, commands, time, string, filecmp
import unittest

class Utility(object):
    ''' common utility class for common test cases  operations'''

    def __init__(self):
        print "constructor"
        pwd = os.getcwd()
        print "Current working directlry %s\n" % pwd
        global scriptpath
        scriptpath = os.path.join(pwd, "src/Runner/")
        maxDiff = int(80)


     def test4_refactoring(self,STATUS,BASE,ANALYSIS_DIR,OUTPUT,log):
            print "common function"
            log.write('\n')
             if (STATUS.lower() == "completed" or STATUS == "Actor : SUCCESS"):
                  self.assertEqual(os.stat(OUTPUT + '/tes1.txt').st_size, 0,
                 'employee count  is not matching with master data . Different  entries are in test1.txt\n')




     but using utility code when i try to execute below statment
     self.assertEqual(os.stat(OUTPUT + '/tes1.txt').st_size, 0,
                 'employee count  is not matching with master data . Different  entries are in test1.txt\n') 


    getting below errors


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/testCases/salesgrowth_DevInt.py", line 96, in test4_refactoring
    utils_obj.test4_refactoring(self.STATUS,self.BASE,self.ANALYSIS_DIR,self.OUTPUT,log)
  File "/src/common/Utils.py", line 436, in test4_refactoring
    'employee count  is not matching with master data. Different entries are in test1.txt\n')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 512, in assertEqual
    assertion_func = self._getAssertEqualityFunc(first, second)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 493, in _getAssertEqualityFunc
    asserter = self._type_equality_funcs.get(type(first))
AttributeError: 'Utility' object has no attribute '_type_equality_funcs'




 Please let me know if any one has any pointers or suggestion for above issue and what is wrong in above implementation.
```

Comment: Great question, I face the same problem, and you did it for me, thanks for making Stackoverflow helping :)

Answer (score 5):

`self.assertEqual` will be only available to classes which inherits `unittest.TestCase` class, which your `Utility` class not doing.

I suggest try putting your `Utility` methods under `BaseTestCase` class.

Give it a name not starting with `test_`, later on call this new function to validate your asserts for numerous other functions.

Comment: Well explain answer

Comment: Can you explain why assertEqual is the only assertion that acts this way?  The rest of the unittest TestCase assertions are able to be called normally when they're subclasses of a class who inherits unittest.