# Python assertEqual error "object has no attribute '_type_equality_funcs'"

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I can't figure out why I'm having the following issue?

The code:

```
from unittest import TestCase


def increment_dictionary_values(d, i):
    for k, v in d.items():
        d[k] = v + i
    return d


class TestIncrementDictionaryValues(TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {'a': 1}

    def test_increment_dictionary_values(self, inc_val, test_val):
        dd = increment_dictionary_values(self.d, inc_val)
        self.assertEquals(dd['a'], test_val, msg="Good")


obj1 = TestIncrementDictionaryValues()
print(obj1.test_increment_dictionary_values(1,2))
```

The error iv got:

```
AttributeError: 'TestIncrementDictionaryValues' object has no attribute '_type_equality_funcs'
```

But if I remove the "**init**" method out of it and put the dictionary in the "TestIncrementDictionaryValues" method, than everything works ok.

Comment: Well, you redefined the __init__() method of TestCase class, and you have no longer access to its attributes.

Comment: If i add ```super(TestIncrementDictionaryValues, self).__init__()``` still i have other error
```TypeError: assertEqual() missing 1 required positional argument: 'second'
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally after some googling and reading this is the work or fix that i have

```
from unittest import TestCase
'''
The other solution im haveing without any error is to remove the __init__ method and place the 
dictionary (d) inside the "test_increment_dictionary_values" method. And this is the basic one. 
But this way we have Class atribuets d and method atributes. 
'''

def increment_dictionary_values(d, i):
    for k, v in d.items():
        d[k] = v + i
    return d


class TestIncrementDictionaryValues(TestCase):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(TestIncrementDictionaryValues, self).__init__()
        self.d = {'a': 1}

    def test_increment_dictionary_values(self, inc_val, test_val):
        dd = increment_dictionary_values(self.d, inc_val)
        self.assertEqual(dd['a'], test_val)


obj1 = TestIncrementDictionaryValues()
print(obj1.test_increment_dictionary_values(1,2))
obj2 = TestIncrementDictionaryValues()
print(obj2.test_increment_dictionary_values(-1,0))
```

This is coped from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978079/attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute-type-equality-funcs)

> self.assertEqual will be only available to classes which inherits unittest.TestCase class, which your Utility class not doing.
> I suggest try putting your Utility methods under BaseTestCase class.
> Give it a name not starting with test_, later on call this new function to validate your asserts for numerous other functions.